# String extraction of numbers without Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, string

First of all, I **can't** use **Pattern** and **Matcher** cause we use **Java 1.5** and those classes are not implemented. I know I can do this by iterating over every character but I think that's sub-optimal.

The pattern to extract is `**`, a number which contains two asterisks `**`

```
Input String = "125, 136, 1**, 154, 200, 201, 250, 2**, 304, 307"
```

Outputs desired:

```
output1 (String) = "125, 136, 154, 200, 201, 250, 304, 307"
output2 (String[]) = [1**],[2**]
```

Comment: You'll have to iterate over all characters anyway (or a library function will). Do you mean optimal in performance or readability ?

Comment: Aren't `Pattern` and `Matcher` from Java 1.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method is to split the numbers using `.split()` and then check the `strings` with `**` in it.

```
String[] s = "125, 136, 1**, 154, 200, 201, 250, 2**, 304, 307".split(", ");
ArrayList<String> withAsterik = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> withoutAsterik = new ArrayList();

for(String str : s)
{
  if(str.contains("**")){
    System.out.println(str);
    withAsterik.add(str);
  }
  else
     withoutAsterik.add(str);
}
```

Comment: I'm working on it, but i don't if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Remember to trim() "str" somewhere

Comment: @Jack Do I really need to trim? the splitting delimiter is `, ` shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Of course you're right. I didn't notice the space within split(). Even if splitting by "," and then trim() would provide a sounder solution. But given this input you're right, my mistake